# не работает шаринг картинок в социальные сети

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема: не удается запостить нужную картинку.

фрагмент html

```
  <div class="wrap-img">
     <div class="share-img-soc">
        <div class="skin skin_light">
           <div class="share-link-list social-likes social-likes_visible">
            <li class="share-img fb social-likes__widget social-likes__widget_facebook" data-service="facebook" data-url="" data-media="" data-image=""><span class="social-likes__button social-likes__button_facebook"><span class="social-likes__icon social-likes__icon_facebook"></span></span><span class="social-likes__counter social-likes__counter_facebook social-likes__counter_empty"></span></li>
            <li class="share-img vk social-likes__widget social-likes__widget_vkontakte" data-service="vkontakte" data-image=""><span class="social-likes__button social-likes__button_vkontakte"><span class="social-likes__icon social-likes__icon_vkontakte"></span></span><span class="social-likes__counter social-likes__counter_vkontakte social-likes__counter_empty"></span></li>
            <li class="share-img ok social-likes__widget social-likes__widget_odnoklassniki" data-service="odnoklassniki" data-image=""><span class="social-likes__button social-likes__button_odnoklassniki"><span class="social-likes__icon social-likes__icon_odnoklassniki"></span></span></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img alt="" src="/images/mclasses/714//image20.jpg" style="width: 450px; height: 600px;">
</div>
```

Описание: при наведении на картинки появляются иконки с соц сетями, по нажатию которых должны постится только та картинка в области которой я произвёл наведение. В данном случае у меня не получается запостить нужную картинку.

Пытаюсь сделать по аналогии как [тут](http://www.livemaster.ru/item/16743601-ukrasheniya-laure-keramicheskie-tsvety-broshi)
jqery

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.share-img', function(){
        var url = $(this).closest('wrap-img').attr('src');

        if($(this).hasClass('fb')){
            window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+url, 'Share Facebook', config='height=300, width=500');
        }




    });
});
```

основная библиотека [отсюда](https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes-next)

Comment: c fb вечно так, картинки достаточно большие?ато маленькие он не подтягивает

Comment: у меня в ширину  600px, обычно это 600x400

Answer (score 1):

Не работает, потому что не берется src: забыли селектор класса (точку) в 'wrap-img' и последующий поиск изображения в блоке. Необходимо делать поиск картинки в DOM-е таким образом:

```
var url = $(this).closest('.wrap-img').children('img').attr('src')
```

плюс надо добавлять `http://имясайта.рф`, относительный путь он не примет

Comment: а если так $(function(){
    $("body").on("click", ".share-img", function(){
   
   var urlImg = $(this).closest(".wrap-img").attr("http://my.site.ru" + src);
   $(".share-img").attr("data-media", urlImg)
   
   

   
  })
 })

Comment: Мне кажется первый вариант все же побыстрее будет, но в принципе, если на эти блоки добавить нужные атрибуты - конечно можно.